# Copy data only from one database to another in SQL Server on the same machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have two databases on my SQL Server 2016 server.

One is a development database that I use for a c++ program I am writing.

The other is a internal production database.

Both DBs are the same except for these point:

- the development DB has a few more triggers than the production database
- the development DB has 2 new columns in a table that I am using for new features.

I want to copy all the data from the production database to the development one.

I tried going into "Generate Scripts..."  but that just writes out scripts to create tables.

I want to just copy over and overwrite all the data for every table.

Is that possible in SQL Server 2016?

Thanks!

Comment: From Management Studio: right-click DB, Tasks -> Import Data (or Export Data, depending on where you start).

Comment: @JeroenMostert so if I need the production data, I do Export Data to a file?  Then goto my development DB and do Import Data?  Will this overwrite all the old data in the development DB(this is what I want)?  thanks

Comment: You don't need a file at all. The import/export wizard can bulk copy directly between instances, regardless of where they are, as long as they're reachable from where you're running Management Studio (in this case, on the same machine). And yes, there is an option to truncate tables before importing. Choosing "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" for your data source type (the bottom option) gives you the simplest interface for specifying the instance/database.

Comment: Note that "Generate Scripts" *also* includes an option to script data as `INSERT`s (under the advanced options). If machines aren't directly reachable and you do want to work with files for some reason, that's another option (though not as fast as bulk copying). If you need to do this in a structured fashion (as part of a deploy pipeline or such) database projects (DACPAC/BACPAC) or other tooling solutions become more attractive.